# How to pick values from json_object based on field matching from list in hive

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

i am working with json_object where for different product categories we have different color variable for ex- `kdt_color`,`fcy_color`, etc. (check below)

How to select appropriate color_variable for each product to extract color value from json_object. There are 100+ verticals so cant use case here.

---

```
{"ctg_ideal_for":["Women"],"ctg_fabric":["Chiffon"],"ctg_design_style":["Umbrella Burqa"],"aba_color":["Black"],"aba_sleeve":["Full Sleeves"],"aba_with_hijab":[true]}

{"blz_color":["single"],"blz_size":["34\"36\"38\"40\"42"],"blz_sleeve_type":["Full Sleeves"],"ctg_ideal_for":["Men"],"ctg_fabric":["Imported"],"ctg_design_style":["Plaid Blazer"]}

{"color":["Multicolor"],"material":["PU"],"ideal_for":["Women"],"closure":["Zipper"],"bpk_style_code":["RMMY2418"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `regexp_extract` to extract `color":["SomeColor` from JSON string like this:

```
select nbr,  regexp_extract(json, 'color":\\["([A-Za-z]*)',1) as color
from
(
select 1 as nbr,  '{"ctg_ideal_for":["Women"],"ctg_fabric":["Chiffon"],"ctg_design_style":["Umbrella Burqa"],"aba_color":["Black"],"aba_sleeve":["Full Sleeves"],"aba_with_hijab":[true]}' as json union all
select 2 as nbr,  '{"blz_color":["single"],"blz_size":["34\"36\"38\"40\"42"],"blz_sleeve_type":["Full Sleeves"],"ctg_ideal_for":["Men"],"ctg_fabric":["Imported"],"ctg_design_style":["Plaid Blazer"]}' as json union all
select 3 as nbr,  '{"color":["Multicolor"],"material":["PU"],"ideal_for":["Women"],"closure":["Zipper"],"bpk_style_code":["RMMY2418"]}' as json
)s;

OK
1       Black
2       single
3       Multicolor
```

You can also use [RegexSerDe](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/58591/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-fields-for-hi.html) to define regex columns in a table DDL.

Comment: In case of multiple values, it doesn't pick all of them.. Any guide for regular expression match...

Comment: @RajatJain Multiple color* attributes in the same JSON object? The right way is to unify JSON and to make all atributes have the same names for all products, then it can be easily parsed using JsonSerDe. Well, in this particular case array (and multiple attributes is an array) is possible to extract using regex as well. Like this: 'color":\\["([A-Za-z,]*\\])' (added comma and ]) then apply split to the extracted value to get an array. did not test, you will have something to do

Comment: got proper regex after some trial and errors which extract values in such case.. thanks for help

Comment: @RajatJain If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept or vote then.